# Not able to create user using keycloak api

Tags: rest, postman, keycloak

Getting token is successful:

```
Post: http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/public-library/protocol/openid-connect/token
Content type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body:x-www-form-urlencoded
client_id:spring-boot-app
username:pooja.kumawat
password:poojakumawat@23
grant_type:password
 Output:Token
```

Creating a user is getting an error:

```
Post : http://localhost:8180/auth/public-library/users
Authorization:Bearer+Token
Content type:Application/Json
Body:Raw
{
   "username": "name",
   "enabled": true,
   "emailVerified": false,
   "firstName": "first",
   "lastName": "last",
   "credentials": [
       {
           "type": "password",
           "value": "newPas1*",
           "temporary": false
       }
   ]
}
```

Error is:

```
{
"error": "RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8180/auth/public-library/users"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the wrong endpoint, change it to

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/public-library/users
```

And keep in mind, the user who is performing the `POST` request need to have at least the `manage-users` realm-management role assigned. Otherwise the response will be 403 Forbidden

Comment: i changed the URL , now it's giving {
    "error": "HTTP 401 Unauthorized"
}

Comment: then you are not properly authenticated or your user missing the required roles / permissions (as i mentioned) - please check that first and if everything is fine the error should go away (otherwise check keycloak error log)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is go to the realm you are using in keycloak. Then go to the users section and select the user you are you using for the request. Under role Mappings, select realm management and assign this user the role **realm admin and manage users** role. After that, you will be able to make requests